# Ruby on Rails CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, crud

I am building an application that allows users to create a trip. However, for some reason I am not sure if I am truly utilizing the power of rails or am I being redundant in my code. In the following example you will see a trip controller where a trip can be created and then displayed. Everything works, I just want to make sure I am going about it in the most minimal fashion.

```
class TripsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @user = User.find(session[:id]) 
    @trip = Trip.new 
end

def create
    @trip = Trip.create(trip_params)
    @user = User.find(session[:id]) 

    redirect_to user_trip_path(@user.id, @trip.id) 
end

def show
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
end

private

def trip_params
    params.require(:trip).permit(:where, :when, :price_per_person)
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

To tighten it up, "scope the trip to the user".

```
class TripsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_user 

  def new
    @trip = @user.trips.build #assuming a User has many trips
  end

  def create
    @trip = @user.trips.create(trip_params) #you may want to add an if else here to catch bad trips

    redirect_to user_trip_path(@user.id, @trip.id) 
  end

  def show
    @trip = @user.trips.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def trip_params
    params.require(:trip).permit(:where, :when, :price_per_person)
  end
  def find_user
     @user = User.find(session[:id]) # or current_user if you are using popular authentication gems
  end
end
```

It's about readability too, not just less lines.

Comment: Does before_filter basically just make it easier so I don't have to keep finding the user through each method? Not too familiar with that..

Comment: In addition, can you elaborate on what popular authentication gems you are referring to? I just know about sessions.

Comment: yes to `before_filter` - that method (the way i wrote it) gets executed before your new, create or show gets fired. Gems, look at Devise, i guess... You can roll your own but most don't. You would be rolling your own. Session Id works for you for now.

Comment: I've just been using session id to validate if a user is signed in always. The most I've done is create a sessions controller, but I always thought it was a lot of work. Would you suggest to drop that and learn to use devise? I'm in the beginning of building this app.

Comment: i see you are new to stack, or your profile is new. If this answer helped do up vote. cheers. You can use devise if  you like, you've got a lot to learn, and well starting with user authentication isn't the best spot. It's just one of a billion things to learn, lol.